# Como tratar o json em java

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando tratar o seguinte json:

```
[{"code":"ARS","codein":"BRL","name":"Peso Argentino (R$)","high":"0.165","low":"0.1638","pctChange":"0.182","open":"0","bid":"0.1643","ask":"0.1647","varBid":"0.0003","timestamp":"1522699200000","create_date":"2018-04-02 20:20:08"}]
```

Estou usando:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("NÃO EXISTE UMA KEY?");
                for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject linha = dados.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.v("valor", linha.getString("high"));
            }
```

Como faço quando não há uma key?

Comment: `JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray($seu_json);` não foi ?

Comment: @RBZ Só uma correçãozinha, no Java não se usa o $ no nome das variáveis.

Comment: Opa ! Que marcada... é o vício do PHP !  :D

Comment: Obrigado @RBZ eu não havia tentado, funcionou aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obrigado @RBZ eu não havia tentado, funcionou aqui. – Emerson
>   Barcellos

Resposta:

```
JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray(seu_json);
```

Eu aprendi uma regra de ouro, basicamente assim:

`[` = JSONArray

`{` = JSONObject